# Attempt on an HR onboarding console application using C#

Tags: c#, delegates, file-read

I am not quite sure how to finish this as this is my first time trying to read and write text files using C#

What I am trying to do with my console application is:

I) Read a list of new employee records from a text file, masterlist.txt from HR. The
HRMasterlist.txt file has full details of new employee records.

II) Generate the txt files that store the required list of new employee records by different department.

**There are different information of new employees needed by each department:**

Corporate Admin Department: FullName, Designation, Department

Procurement Department: Salutation, FullName, MobileNo, Designation, Department

IT Department: Nric, FullName, StartDate, Department, MobileNo

**This is what I have done so far:**

Employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;
namespace SectionA
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee(string nric, string fullname, string salutation, DateTime startdate, string designation, string department, string mobileno, string hiretype, double salary)
        {
            this.Nric = nric;
            this.FullName = fullname;
            this.Salutation = salutation;
            this.StartDate = startdate;
            this.Designation = designation;
            this.Department = department;
            this.MobileNo = mobileno;
            this.HireType = hiretype;
            this.Salary = salary;
            this.MonthlyPayout = 0.0;
        }
        public string Nric { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Salutation { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string HireType { get; set; }
        public double Salary {get; set;}
        public double MonthlyPayout {get; set;}
        
        public string forCorpAdmin(Employee that)
        {
            return //add code;
        }
        public string forProcurement()
        {
            return //add code;
        }

        public string forITDept()
        {
            return //add code;
        }

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
namespace SectionA
{
    public delegate void GenerateTxtFile();
    public class Program
    {
       
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> emps= new List<Employee>()
            emps = readHRMasterList();
           
           generateInfoForCorpAdmin(emps);
           generateInfoForProcurement(emps);
           enerateInfoForITDepartment(emps)

           //when above can work, do delegate


        }

        public static List<Employee> readHRMasterList(List<Employee> emps)
        {
            string path = @"../HRMasterlist.txt";
           //add code to read the HRMasterlist.txt
           // use each row of data to create a employee object
            //store each object into the employee before you return to main()
            return emps;
        }

        public static void generateInfoForCorpAdmin(List<Employee> emps)
        {
            //• CorporateAdmin: FullName, Designation, Department
            //open a new file "CorporateAdmin.txt" and store the above format into the file
            //how to get the data frome the employee list pass in
                
        }
        public static void generateInfoForProcurement(List<Employee> emps)
        {
            //• Procurement: Salutation, FullName, MobileNo, Designation, Department
            //add code
        }

        public static void generateInfoForITDepartment()
        {
            //• ITDepartment: Nric, FullName, StartDate, Department, MobileNo
            //add code

        }

    }
}
```

And finally, HRMasterList.txt

```
S1234567A|Jan Lee|Ms|05/10/1990|Software Architect|IT Department|98785432|PartTime|3500
S1234567B|Feb Tan|Mr|10/12/1991|Corporate Recruiter|HR Corporate Admin|98766432|PartTime|1500
S1234567C|Mark Lim|Mr|15/07/1992|Benefit Specialist|HR Corporate Admin|98265432|PartTime|2900
S1234567D|Apr Tan|Ms|20/01/1996|Payroll Administrator|HR Corporate Admin|91765432|FullTime|1600
S1234567E|May Ng|Ms|25/05/1994|Training Coordinator|HR Corporate Admin|98767432|Hourly|1200
S1234567F|Juno Chua|Mr|30/09/1997|Compensation Manager|HR Corporate Admin|98760432|FullTime|4000
S1234567G|Jul Wang|Mr|02/03/1996|Technical Recruiter|HR Corporate Admin|98765932|PartTime|1200
S1234567H|Aug Lau|Mr|04/11/1997|HR Consultant|HR Corporate Admin|98765032|PartTime|2000
S1234567I|Sep Yeo|Mr|06/08/1998|Software Engineer|IT Department|98765434|FullTime|3000
S1234567J|Octo Chua|Mr|08/04/1999|Technical Lead|IT Department|92765432|FullTime|4000
S1234567K|Nova Ng|Ms|10/03/1980|Team Lead|IT Department|90760432|FullTime|3000
S1234567L|Dessy Chow|Ms|05/01/1998|Project Lead|IT Department|95760432|FullTime|3500
S1234567M|Jack Mar|Mr|14/06/1999|Project Manager|IT Department|98766632|FullTime|4500
S1234567N|Anne Chan|Ms|16/04/1983|Procurement Assistant|Procurement Department|90065432|Hourly|1000
S1234567O|Claire Tan|Ms|17/08/1984|Procurement Officer|Procurement Department|98760032|FullTime|1000
S1234567P|Jade Lau|Ms|18/10/1996|Purchasing Associate|Procurement Department|91711432|FullTime|1100
S1234567Q|Wyne Yeo|Ms|19/08/1986|Purchasing Clerk|Procurement Department|98733433|Hourly|1200
S1234567R|Craig Ng|Mr|23/11/1987|Facilities Manager|Procurement Department|90088432|PartTime|2000
S1234567S|Hugh Chan|Mr|25/05/1988|Operations Manager|Procurement Department|88765432|FullTime|2500
S1234567T|Kent Teo|Mr|27/11/1989|Store Manager|Procurement Department|80765432|FullTime|2000
S1234567U|Sam Goh|Mr|29/03/1990|Production Planner|Procurement Department|98765321|Hourly|1500
S1234567V|Zack Aw|Mr|13/12/1991|Warehouse Clerk|Procurement Department|98321432|Hourly|1000
S1234567W|Ava Lim|Ms|07/11/1992|Procurement Specialist|Procurement Department|91235432|PartTime|2800
S1234567X|Eva Chow|Ms|09/12/1997|Materials Director|Procurement Department|92225432|FullTime|6500
S1234567Y|Lea Law|Ms|11/07/1994|Corporate Recruiter|HR Corporate Admin|94445432|PartTime|1600
S1234567Z|Ian Neo|Ms|21/09/1995|HR Coordinator|HR Corporate Admin|90005432|Hourly|1200
```

Comment: See the static methods of the [File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0#methods) (e.g. [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_). And the [String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) and the static [String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //read all employees from files
        var employees = ReadEmployes(@"filepathhere");

        //store for the different departments
        var coprateAdmins = new List<string>();
        var procurementDept = new List<string>();
        var itDept = new List<string>();


        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            //classify employee here with switch case on department

            switch (employee.Department)
            {
                case "IT Department":
                    itDept.Add(ToString(employee));
                    break;
                case "HR Corporate Admin":
                    coprateAdmins.Add(ToString(employee));
                    break;

                case "Procurement Department":
                    procurementDept.Add(ToString(employee));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        //writing files stage feel free to rename as accordingly
        WriteFile("IT.txt", itDept);
        WriteFile("procurement.txt", procurementDept);
        WriteFile("coporateAdmins.txt", coprateAdmins);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// helper function to write files given names
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="employees"></param>
    private static void WriteFile(string name, List<string> employees)
    {

        File.WriteAllLines(name, employees);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// helper function to read employees from a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">path of the text file</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Employee> ReadEmployes(string path)
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        
        //the employees will be read separated by new lines
        var content = File.ReadAllText(path);

        //split by new line into an array of employee information in text
        var lines = content.Split('\n');

        //map each employee with their properies assumes all records will have the same order in columns
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var properties = line.Split('|');

            employees.Add(new Employee
            {
                Nric = properties[0],
                FullName = properties[1],
                Salutation = properties[2],
                StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(properties[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Designation = properties[4],
                Department = properties[5],
                MobileNo = properties[6],
                HireType = properties[7],
                Salary = double.Parse(properties[8])
            });
        }

        return employees;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// helper function that uses c# reflection to get an employees properties then map to a string format similar to your input file
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="instance"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToString<T>(T instance)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.GetValue(instance) != null)
            {
                builder.Append(pi.GetValue(instance));
                builder.Append('|');
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

}


/// <summary>
/// employee details
/// </summary>
public class Employee
{
    public string Nric { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string HireType { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public double MonthlyPayout { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// coroporate admin model
/// </summary>
public class CorporateAdmin
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// procurement model
/// </summary>
public class ProcurementDepartment
{
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// it deparment model
/// </summary>
public class ITDepartment
{
    public string Nric { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

}